# SetEndOfFile vs SetFileInformationByHandle to extend file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I can set file size with [SetFilePointerEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542(v=vs.85).aspx) followed by [SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx).Or, I can do it with [SetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539(v=vs.85).aspx) with FileEndOfFileInfo. Is there any difference in behavior? SetFileInformationByHandle seems more straightforward, but has by far less google hits on some reason.

Comment: The winapi used to be simple.  And then they had to add SFIBH to make it more complicated to make everybody happy.  Keep it simple.

Comment: of course much better direct use `SetFileInformationByHandle`. the `SetEndOfFile` first query file pointer and then call `ZwSetInformationFile` with `FileEndOfFileInformation` information. the `SetFileInformationByHandle` do the same, but use your information instead. for what do several calls to kernel instead single ?

Comment: Well, Simple is good. However, fiddling with file pointer in general case needs some locks and resets for the file pointer. SFIBH can do without, so it  seems more attractive.

Comment: @RbMm: If it makes code easier to read, understand, and maintain, taking two trips to the kernel instead of one is more often than not worth it.

Comment: @IInspectable - why you think that use `SetFilePointerEx` followed by `SetEndOfFile` more easy than single call `SetFileInformationByHandle` ? and not 2 calls to kernel in first scenario but 3 or 4

Comment: There is no difference in behaviour.  Use whichever one suits your particular scenario.  If you're accessing the same file from multiple threads, that's probably SetFileInformationByHandle.

Comment: also thin different - `SetEndOfFile` after call to `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileEndOfFileInfo` than call `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileAllocationInfo` - this force file system allocate additional memory for file or free it. actual code for `SetEndOfFile` - https://doxygen.reactos.org/da/d02/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2file_2fileinfo_8c_source.html#l01133

Comment: @RbMm that is not official Microsoft source code. ReactOS is not Windows, it is a 3rd party open source OS that is compatible with Windows apps by emulating the Win32 API interfaces, but it can do whatever it wants internally

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, I know. but I look asm code for `SetEndOfFile` too. and second call for `FileAllocationInformation` exist

Comment: @RbMm: The issue here is, that the only optimization you know of is performance. Developers that work in teams usually optimize for readability first, and setting the current file pointer followed by marking it as the end of file is a natural way to express that intent. `SetFileInformationByHandle` is a powerful alternative. That power comes with much complexity. Compare its documentation to the documentation for `SetFilePointerEx`/`SetEndOfFile`, and you'll probably agree.

Comment: @IInspectable, the only real issue  here is documentation. *if* `SetFileInformationByHandle` was better documented, *and* it corresponded exactly to `SetFilePointerEx/SetEndOfFile` do, I dont't see why one call where parameters clearly indicate  the intent is more complicated than moving file pointer to offset and "set EOF here"

Comment: Even if the documentation were better, `SetFileInformationByHandle` is still a complex beast, with lots of overloads. As it stands, the documentation is as good as it is, and I was taking this into account when challenging the statement, that `SetFileInformationByHandle` were unconditionally much better. It may be better, for some use cases, in some teams, for some applications.